# Do we ever need memory barriers with C++ atomics on Intel x86?

Tags: c++, multithreading, assembly, concurrency, atomic

I thought only string and (certain) streaming instructions require memory barriers on Intel x86? For all other instructions the Intel strong memory ordering model ensures that consistency is achieved?

**Assuming the above is correct, why do we need to use C++ atomics (excluding compare-and-exchange) when our code is only executing on Intel x86?**

I really am getting myself confused where we need to use atomics and whether using atomics inhibits the out-of-order-execution due to memory barriers and then the whole MESI protocol.

**MESI just ensures the caches are consistent across all processors?**

**Memory barriers are useful on other architectures because they flush the CPU store buffers to the caches, to allow MESI to ensure consistency?**

**When do we need to use atomics on Intel X86 CPUs?**

Comment: Related: http://bartoszmilewski.com/2008/11/05/who-ordered-memory-fences-on-an-x86/

Comment: Assuming the above is correct - it isn't. Intel needs barriers even for acquire/release semantics. x86 offers incredibly expensive and at the same time still rather limited ordering guarantees for practical programming. Basically you need a barrier (mfence, locked instruction) for StoreLoad barriers.

Comment: @Voo: I'm not an expert, but AFAIK a StoreLoad barrier isn't really needed that often. I don't see how one could describe the x86 memory ordering as "rather limited for practical programming". For practical programming *I* usually require release/acquire semantics, which Intel provides without any explicit barriers.

Comment: @Paul Acquire/release requires StoreLoad barriers, so no you certainly do need barriers on x86 too. And that's the point: you get lots of guarantees you don't need most of the time and when you actually write multi threaded code you still need explicit barriers (or locked instructions).

Comment: @Voo: Acquire/release certainly does *not* require a StoreLoad barrier!

Comment: @Paul Could you show me the statement in the Intel docs where it says that loads cannot be reordered with preceding stores? And if that were true, what exactly would mfence exist for (well it'd be a rather fancy nop)? Also [JSR133 cookbook](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html) which is for Java but deals with the same acquire/release semantics and claims the same thing. Gcc also generates mfence instructions after atomic stores.

Comment: @Voo: IDK if we're talking about the same thing. What I'm talking about are operations with acquire semantics and operations with release semantics. Which do neither require a StoreLoad barrier nor a full fence. And GCC *does not* generate an mfence after a `std::atomic<int>::store(x, memory_order_release)`. See https://goo.gl/XcozsM

Comment: @Voo: And mfence is of course required for a full barrier. Only a full barrier is not necessary for acquire/release. Therefor mfence is not necessary for acquire/release. That doesn't mean it's completely useless. It only means we don't need it as long as we can do what we need with only acquire and release semantics. ps: better example, including a load between the acquire and release: https://goo.gl/oJjVXG

Comment: @Paul I was wrong, thanks for correcting me. Now have to look up why the JMM needs that barrier on x86 then, weird.

Comment: @Voo: You're welcome ;) Maybe the Java memory model provides stricter guarantees? E.g. if it would guarantee sequential consistency for all volatile loads/stores then the naked store wouldn't be enough. And it might guarantee that, in an ill advised attempt to make volatile accesses powerful enough to implement most lock free algorithms - thereby crippling volatile store performance (instead of providing a utility class for atomic operations with various memory orderings). BTW: I just love gcc.godbolt.org - such a useful tool!

Answer (score 3):

While X86 is cache-coherent, it doesn't mean it gives you the guarantees you expect to find. There are different instructions for atomic save and regular save and they behave differently.
Also, and equally importantly, atomic variables prevent 'destructive' compiler optimizations. Without those, the compiler will easily optimize your code according to single-threaded execution model, and your programm will misbehave.

Comment: Do atomic operations prevent processor reordering issues in a multi-threaded program, or would memory barrier operations be needed?

Comment: They do when used accordingly. There are 6 different memory models which you can use with atomics, and one of those is 'relaxed', which does not give you any guarantees at all. 
The default (sequential) ensures 'full reordering block' (both in regards to loads and stores). Actually, linguistically you either speak in terms of fences or in terms of atomics - atomics and memory models never mention fence (which is implementation detail), instead, they talk about order and predictability.

Comment: @SergeyA: What do you mean by *"there are different instructions for atomic save and regular save and they behave differently"*? AFAIK a normal load/store on x86 is always atomic if the address is aligned, each load has acquire semantics and each store release semantics. Which, aside from CAS, is pretty much all you need. Also, what you refer to as memory models are actually "memory orders".

Comment: @Paul, I was answering the question as it was asked. Non-chip specific, but rather a C++ question without specific chip affinity. When taken as such, I'd hope you agree with my answer. As for terminology, you are right to correct me. Memory model came from some deeps of my mind.

Comment: @SergeyA: Ah, OK. Your first sentence explicitly mentiones x86, so I assumed that when you wrote *"there are different instructions for ..."* you were still referring to x86 (="x86 has different instructions..."). I can see however that one can also interpret it differently, i.e. "C++ has different instructions...". Still I find the phrasing a little confusing.

Comment: Also, mfence plays role even on Intel chip )

Comment: Agree with better wording might be appropriate.

Comment: The `relaxed` memory order does in fact give you a guarantee, that of atomicity. Which is to say that the memory order is anything but interleaved.

Comment: @PaulGroke They have acquire and release semantics at the assembly language level. There's no guarantee these will "pass through" a C++ compiler.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, yes, I do know that :) Only I though Sergey was still talking about the assembly level when he wrote *"there are different instructions for atomic save and regular save"*. Which he apparently was not. Therefor my confusion.

Comment: And I totally agree with @PaulGroke, but I will not edit my answer least all this wonderful comment chain will suddenly become meaningless :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to forget about the specific architecture that you compile against. You're programming C++, and that means you can only rely on the guarantees that your specific C++ implementation gives you. This *should* of course include whatever the Standard guarantees. In addition you *might* get some additional guarantees from your specific C++ implementation.

The reason is that the C++ implementation is allowed to do pretty much everything, as long as it doesn't break the rules of the C++ Standard. That means it may "remove" or "destroy" some guarantees that the platform you're compiling against would "normally" provide (meaning: when you program it in assembler). E.g. it might use string/MMX/SSE/SSE2/... instructions where you don't expect it, reorder instructions, coalesce writes, place non-atomic data at addresses that aren't suitably aligned for atomicity etc.

That being said, there is at least one C++ implementation that gives you rather strong additional guarantees about memory ordering, and that is Visual C++. It guarantees that volatile loads always have acquire semantics and volatile stores always have release semantics. (At least on x86/amd64 with default compiler settings.) It also guarantees that properly aligned volatile reads and writes are atomic. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd.aspx) for details.

Comment: Visual C++ has targeted ARM (and probably MIPS) for at least a decade. Windows CE and later Windows Phone required it.

Comment: @MSalters, thanks for that tip, I removed the speculation.

Comment: You may want to refer to [/volatile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd.aspx). This explains the settings for ARM, x86 and x64, as well as the defaults.

Comment: Done. But that shows that my original speculation was true after all. The `/volatile` switch, controlling that extension, is new in VS 2012, which IIRC is the first (non-"embedded") VS version to provide a non-x86 compiler. So VC++ might have targeted other platforms internally, but no such compiler was publicly available with normal VS versions.

Comment: The ARM compiler indeed didn't ship in the Visual Studio for Desktop products. But the last "embedded" version of Visual Studio was eVC++ 4.0. VS2005 didn't ship with an ARM compiler, but that compiler came as part of the Windows Mobile SDK and did integrate with VS2005. The change with VS2012 was for Windows Phone 8, which is no longer part of the Windows CE line but is now on the Windows NT line.  That also meant no separate SDK was needed, so you also couldn't get the ARM compiler from there.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought only string and (certain) streaming instructions require memory barriers on Intel x86? For all other instructions the Intel strong memory ordering model ensures that consistency is achieved?

This is true *at the assembly language level*.

> Assuming the above is correct, why do we need to use C++ atomics (excluding compare-and-exchange) when our code is only executing on Intel x86?

How else would you perform atomic operations like compare and exchange? Atomicity and memory visibility have almost nothing to do with each other.

> I really am getting myself confused where we need to use atomics and whether using atomics inhibits the out-of-order-execution due to memory barriers and then the whole MESI protocol.

We need to use atomics where we need atomicity. We need to use memory barriers where we need memory visibility because even though the x86's assembly language memory model might not require them, there's no guarantee this will "pass through" the compiler seamlessly to the C++ level.